# How to start redis with specific .rdb file?

Tags: redis, redis-cli, redis-server

I had redis installed without password. Then I tried to put password without success and decided to delete all related to redis from my server. After that, I've installed redis once again and set a password successfully. The problem is that now is creating a new database and not reading from the old one. I am running the same command from sabe directory. `$~/ redis-server`

I've also tried to check if is generating a new dump.rdb file with:

```
find / -type f -name "*.rdb"
```

But is only finding my correct `dump.rdb` file that I'd like to use.

Is there a way to import my last database to this new one? Or, Is there a way to start my server using the `correct dump.rdb` file?

Comment: How did you delete previous data ? Did you `FLUSHALL` ?

Comment: No, I've opened the file to check and is everything there..

Comment: Make sure that your .conf's `dir` directive is set to the directory where your RDB file is. Furthermore, verify that the filename matches to the value in `dbfilename`. If these are set correctly and still no luck - what does the log say?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I move a redis database from one server to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004915/how-do-i-move-a-redis-database-from-one-server-to-another)

Answer (score 6):

The Simplest way to go is

```
redis-server --dbfilename dump.rdb --dir /home/in_which_directory_rdb_file_exists
```

Change the `.rdb file name` and the `directory` name as per your requirements.

Answer (score 4):

Copy your rdb file to correct path:

```
sudo cp /path/to/rdb/dump.rdb /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb
```

Make redis owner of new rdb file:

```
sudo chown redis: /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb
```

Open redis config file in `/etc/redis/redis.conf`.

Make sure these two lines are existed and not commented:

```
dbfilename dump.rdb
dir /var/lib/redis
```

Turn off other persistence method by changing `appendonly` option to `no` (because `redis` will consider that method first):

```
appendonly yes
```

Save and close the config file and restart `redis-server`:

```
systemctl restart redis-server
```

This will work if `redis-server` is compatible with your `rb` file.